# Error when starting a new project of C Cpp in eclipse

Tags: c++, c, eclipse, compiler-errors

When using Eclipse for C C++ operations it shows this error. I have installed mingw64 and jdk14, also in the system variables>> added both bin path there.
"**An internal error occurred during: "Load QML Analyzer". java.lang.NullPointerException**"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just found this on the web. It worked for me. Might help you as well, if you still need it.

"If you need the Qt plug-ins, the workaround is to downgrade to Java 14. Otherwise, to get rid of the message box, it is possible to uninstall the Qt plugins:

- go to the Eclipse menu → (Help →) About Eclipse IDE
- click the Installation Details button
- click the Installed Software tab
- select the C/C++ Qt Support feature
- click the Uninstall button
- click Finish"

Answer (score 0):

From this [link](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/1105354/):

> you are probably running with Java 15 which has yet again removed some
> packages/libraries that were previous available. You should have
> better luck running the IDE with Java 14.